# Actual and Estimated rows differ greatly

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, cardinality-estimates

[The full Actual plan is here.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H14c2tRcY)

Prior to executing the plan (because I'm debugging a poorly functioning plan) I have this block of variable assignments:

```
DECLARE @Days INT = 180
DECLARE @DateRangeFrom DateTime = DATEADD(d, -@Days, getDate())
DECLARE @DateRangeTo DateTime = getDate()
DECLARE @FacilityID INT = 1010
DECLARE @Answer0 INT = 1879
DECLARE @Answer1 INT = 1949
DECLARE @Answer1SetID INT = 1607
DECLARE @Answer2 INT = 1907
DECLARE @Answer2SetID INT = 1593
```

My first problem is with the lookup I'm performing on the IRItemAnswer_Info table (Node ID 19).  It's spilling to Tempdb which already starts the query off on the wrong foot.
It's referencing the `IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerSourceID` index, which is the correct index, as I'm matching on `DGItemID` and `AnswerSourceID`, and getting back `IncidentID`.  The index is created as

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerSourceID
ON dbo.IRItemAnswer_Info (DGItemID, AnswerSourceID) 
INCLUDE([IncidentID], [AnswerBoolean])
```

However, the Estimated Rows for the query is 53,459 and the Actual Rows is 969,812.

I just finished forcing new statistics via `UPDATE STATISTICS IRItemAnswer_Info IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerSourceID WITH FULLSCAN` and it made no difference.

`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('IRItemAnswer_Info', 'DGItemID')` for `DGItemID=1949` has `EQ_ROWS` as `1,063,536` and

`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('IRItemAnswer_Info', 'AnswerSourceID')` for `AnswerSourceID=1607` has `EQ_ROWS` as `970,079`

The database is running Compatibility level 140 (SQL Server 2017).  We would run 2019, but there are issues we need to correct in the stored procedures before we can do that.

What should be the next thing I look at?

---

I chose the worst performing output, which is the most common values.  `IRItemAnswer_Info` is a table containing user-defined answers to associate to an event, where `DGItemID=1949` is one of the most common questions (almost every event has one), and where `AnswerSourceID=1607` is the most common answer.  Given that there is a strong correlation between them, how should I reorder the query?

As it is a point of a little bit of confusion, there are two `INNER JOIN`s to the same table, `IRItemAnswer_Info`.  One is the answer I'm looking for (as identified by the question `iria.DGItemID=1879` and its output `iria.AnswerSourceID` links to `irai.AltLabel`), and the second one is a limiting factor.  I only want records where the question `iiai1.DGItemID=1949` has as its answer `iiai1.AnswerSourceID=1607`.

I have explicitly removed the plan from the cache (using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`) and re-run it, with no change in the result - the Hash Match is still spilling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the related Q & A [How does SQL Server know predicates are correlated?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20597) SQL Server assumes predicates are completely independent by default.

It only has detailed statistical information (histograms) on the single leading column, even where multi-column indexes or statistics are used. The question then is how to combine two statistics histograms from two separate predicates.

For example, say you have a query with `WHERE c1 = x AND c2 = y`. The selectivity of `c1 = x` is computed to be 0.2 from histogram information. The selectivity of `c2 = y` is computed to be 0.1 from a separate histogram.

What is the selectivity of the two predicates together? 0.2? 0.1? 0.2 x 0.1? Somewhere in between?

Without specific additional information, SQL Server has to make an educated guess. The original default was to assume complete independence. The newer cardinality estimation framework uses [exponential backoff](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates) (the 'somewhere in between' option).

Your case is slightly different, in that you have two equality tests on columns in a multi-column index, which comes with multi-column statistics. These are not so grand as they might sound. We still only get a histogram on the leading column, but the statistics object does contain average density information for multiple columns.

For example an index on (a,b,c) would provide density information for (a), (a,b), and (a,b,c). This frequency information does capture something about correlation, but it is a single number at each level. This means a frequency-based estimate will always produce the same estimate given the same number of columns.

SQL Server does produce a selectivity estimate from the multi-column frequency information, but it also computes selectivity from the individual column histograms (where available). The histogram estimate assumes independence, and does not use exponential backoff.

The server chooses the histogram-based estimate if it is a higher selectivity than the frequency-based estimate. This appears to be the case in your example.

```
Plan for computation:

  CSelCalcPointPredsFreqBased
      Distinct value calculation:
          CDVCPlanLeaf
              1 Multi-Column Stats, 0 Single-Column Stats, 0 Guesses

      Individual selectivity calculations:
          CSelCalcColumnInInterval
              Column: QCOL: [IIAI].DGItemID

          CSelCalcColumnInInterval
              Column: QCOL: [IIAI].AnswerSourceID

Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [IIAI].DGItemID from stats with id 2
Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [IIAI].AnswerSourceID from stats with id 3

Cardinality using multi-column statistics 5.45574e-07 and 
with independence assumption 0.00231336. 
Picking cardinality 0.00231336

Selectivity: 0.00231336
```

From information in the question, the individual selectivities are:

- DGItemID = 1063536 out of 19299400
- AnswerSourceID = 970079 out of 19299400

Assuming independence, for `AND` we multiply those selectivities then multiply by the full table cardinality to produce the row estimate:

```
19299400 * (1063536/19299400 * 970079/19299400) = 53458.3427124.
```

There are a number of internal model variations that approach the task in different ways. Only a few are publicly documented and exposed via hints or trace flags.

Ordinarily, it would seem that the following hint could be helpful:

```
SELECT
    COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM [VaxxTracker].[dbo].[IRItemAnswer_Info] AS iiai1
WHERE
    iiai1.DGItemID = 1949 
    AND iiai1.AnswerSourceID = 1607
OPTION (USE HINT('ASSUME_MIN_SELECTIVITY_FOR_FILTER_ESTIMATES'));
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#use_hint)

> - 'ASSUME_MIN_SELECTIVITY_FOR_FILTER_ESTIMATES'
>   Causes SQL Server to generate a plan using minimum selectivity when estimating AND predicates for filters to account for full correlation. This hint name is equivalent to trace flag 4137 when used with cardinality estimation model of SQL Server 2012 (11.x) and earlier versions, and has similar effect when trace flag 9471 is used with cardinality estimation model of SQL Server 2014 (12.x) or higher.

Unfortunately, that hint does not apply when cardinality estimation started with a frequency-based calculation, using multi-column statistics.

You *might* get a better result in your case using the original CE model:

```
USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION')
```

Comment: Hohlee!  Using `USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION')` corrected all of the cardinality estimates, and the query which ran for 22 seconds without it, ran for only 5 with it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this index instead

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IRItemAnswerInfo_DGItemID_AnswerSourceID
ON dbo.IRItemAnswer_Info (DGItemID, AnswerSourceID,[IncidentID])
INCLUDE([AnswerBoolean])
```

The other thing I'd consider if this doesn't help is troubleshooting the index as a single select (no joins) and putting the results directly into a temp table, and then join to it later.

For example, try something like the below query, and see if you can get goed estimates. If you can, that should confirm you've found the right index. Then tie everything else back in.

```
SELECT *
FROM IRItemAnswer_Inf
WHERE IncidentID = @IncidentId
    AND DGItemID = @Answer1
    AND AnswerSourceID = @Answer1SetID
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try, with the following rewrite :

```
WITH 
Phases (PhaseID) AS
(
SELECT IRPhaseSID
FROM   IncidentPhase_Code
WHERE  IRPhaseSID > 0
  AND  IRPhaseSID <> 1002

UNION ALL

SELECT IRPhaseSID
FROM   IncidentPhase_Code
WHERE  IRPhaseSID = -3
),
CTE (Age, IncidentID) AS
(
SELECT irai.AltLabel, 
       iria.IncidentID
FROM  IRItemAnswer_Info iria WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN Incident_Info inci WITH(NOLOCK) ON inci.IncidentSID = iria.IncidentID
      INNER JOIN Phases ON Phases.PhaseID = inci.IRPhaseID
      INNER JOIN IncidentType_XRef intx WITH(NOLOCK) ON intx.IncidentID = inci.IncidentSID
      INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentTypeHierarchy_GetChildNodeIDs(1666) ithc ON ithc.IncidentTypeNodeSID = intx.IncidentTypeNodeID
      INNER JOIN IRDGroupItem_Info idgi WITH(NOLOCK) ON idgi.DGItemSID = iria.DGItemID
      INNER JOIN IRAlternative_Info irai WITH(NOLOCK) ON irai.AltSID = iria.AnswerSourceID
      INNER JOIN IRItemAnswer_Info iiai1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON iiai1.IncidentID = inci.IncidentSID
                                                         AND iiai1.DGItemID = @Answer1
                                                         AND iiai1.AnswerSourceID = @Answer1SetID
WHERE iria.DGItemID = 1879
      AND iria.AnswerBoolean = 1
      AND (inci.IncidentDate >= @DateRangeFrom)
      AND (inci.IncidentDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @DateRangeTo))
      AND (inci.FacilityID = @FacilityID)
               
)
SELECT Age AS Label, 
      COUNT(IncidentID) AS Cnt
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Cnt DESC OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this query.

The modified query produces [this plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1s-Ccyit).  Though using a  `UNION` instead of an `AND` (which is better query management) produces two Seeks instead of a Scan (on a small lookup table) they otherwise produce identical plans, and still doesn't avoid the tempdb spill in Nodes 19 and 20.

Comment: I am interested to see what is in "dbo.IncidentTypeHierarchy_GetChildNodeIDs(...)" ??? Also I would know why you put "iiai1.DGItemID = @Answer1 AND iiai1.AnswerSourceID = @Answer1SetID" in the INNER JOIN instead of the WHERE clause ?

Comment: `dbo.IncidentTypeHierarchy_GetChildNodeIDs(1666)` returns a table of 3 `IncidentTypeNodeSID` values, which is important for selectivity of the results.
As for the `INNER JOIN IRItemAnswer_Info iiai1`, I could have written it as an `WHERE EXISTS` statement, it would have had the same effect.

Answer (score -2):

You could also try with :

```
SELECT IRPhaseSID
FROM   IncidentPhase_Code
WHERE  IRPhaseSID > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT IRPhaseSID
FROM   IncidentPhase_Code
WHERE  IRPhaseSID = -3

EXCEPT 

SELECT IRPhaseSID
FROM   IncidentPhase_Code
WHERE  IRPhaseSID = 1002
```

Answer (score -2):

At least, check if you have those indexes :

1. IRItemAnswer_Info (DGItemID, AnswerBoolean, IncidentID,
   AnswerSourceID)
2. Incident_Info (FacilityID, IncidentDate, IncidentSID, IRPhaseID)
3. Phases (PhaseID)
4. IncidentType_XRef (IncidentID, IncidentTypeNodeID)
5. IRDGroupItem_Info (DGItemSID)
6. IRAlternative_Info (AltSID) INCLUDE (AltLabel)
7. IRItemAnswer_Info (DGItemID, AnswerSourceID, IncidentID)

If not create it and test...